# UITableView headerView different sizes

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, tableview

I'm trying to apply a size on my UITableView headerView but it seems like the first section header always is a bit smaller than the rest section headerViews. I've said the constraints for the UITableView so it should be fine. How come the first section is smaller?

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return ""
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 20
}
```

Comment: Looks to me that your UITableView is not placed correctly. If you pull down the UITableView (it will pull down), does the header show correctly ?

Comment: i've just filled the tableView to fit the whole uivieController and used the recommended constraints.

Comment: The question was other. Did you try pulling down the UITableView and see if the header is correctly sized, but hidden under the UINavigationBar ?

Comment: i've instead creating a UITableViewController and i still seem to have this problem

Comment: I'm curious how you changed the color of the table view header, and font of text.

Comment: I've got the same problem but the answer doesn't work for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior occurs when using a Grouped UITableView.  The section header height appears shorter for the first section header, because it doesn't have a footer above of it.  However, every section header after the first one, does have a footer directly above it.  The footers have a default height, which is contributing to the overall height appearance of the section header.  Therefore, set the section footer heights so the space between the group sections will have the same visual height.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.min
}
```

We use CGFloat.min instead of 0, because returning 0 will cause the footer to return a default height.

Comment: Swift 3: `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude`